flutter_native_splash not showing image
pubspec.yaml:
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
      - assets/ 

flutter_native_splash:
  android: true
  ios: true
  color: "#ffffff"
  image: assets/icon.png
  android_12:
    color: "#ffffff"
    image: assets/icon.png

And I added the android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" in the activity tag. I also checked that the image path is ok, and actually, if I use that image as background and remove the color the image is displayed (although stretched). Testing in an Android 10 and flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.1. Is there any other configuration I may be missing?

Problem was my phone is set to dark theme and apparently they are needed even when the documentation says they are not.
